# the page is refreshed every time when is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an aspx page the get a value from url .

the page's code is like this :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="confirmpayment.aspx.cs" Inherits="AccidentCongress.UserPortal.confirmpayment" %>

       <div id="bankform"></div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function postRefId(refIdValue) {
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
            form.setAttribute("action", "<% System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PgwSite"].ToString(); %>");
            form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "RefId");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", refIdValue);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField); document.getElementById("bankform").appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
            document.getElementById("bankform").removeChild(form);
        }
</script>
    <%
        if (Request.QueryString["po"] == "true")
        {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> postRefId('" + Request.QueryString["rid"] + "');</script>");

        }
    %>
```

But when i call this page the page is refreshed ,and this part of code is executed every time :

```
<%
            if (Request.QueryString["po"] == "true")
            {
                Response.Write("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> postRefId('" + Request.QueryString["rid"] + "');</script>");

            }
        %>
```

Why?

Best regards

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? Submitting a form will reload page based on form `action` unless you submit using ajax

Comment: I expect that this form redirect me to another website that i should pay some money using bank gateway

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
 form.submit();
```

in your javascript function call

Comment: So i need to post some value to another url because of that i use this

Comment: THe form should be submitted for one time

Comment: I am so beginner how can i do that?

Comment: Please add more detail to make this answer correct.

Comment: @rfornal I have a problem with "postRefId": this code cause redirect from code behind. Since I use ajax, I need to pass params back and then on the main calling page I can execute directly it. But it say postRefId is not defined? what is best replacement or equal for postRefId?